# How to upload a XML file using HTTPS upload (REST)

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, file-upload, https

When I submit a simple form like this with a file attached:

```
<form name="bilupload" action="https://localhost:3000/finn/import/fileimport" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

fil: <input TYPE="FILE" NAME="fil" size="30">

<input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

How does it send the file internally? Is the file sent as part of the HTTP body as data? In the headers of this request, I don't see anything related to the name of the file.

I just would like the know the internal workings of the HTTP when sending a file.

I try this:

```
HTTP.post("https://localhost:3000/finn/import/fileimport", {

    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
               name: "fil",
               filename:"finn.xml"
             },
     data: XMLDate

     }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
           console.log("err", err);
        } else {
           console.log("result", result);
        }
 });
```

Comment: Just to understand: do you want to upload from Meteor to some REST endpoint or from another app to your Meteor app?

Comment: My meteor app to another app

Comment: If it is only XML or any other plain text based format you could also just send the XML String or file content and save it as file on the server after received. Makes things much easier. Does not solve the binary upload but just as an idea to simply.